# How to to make custom shape with flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make a custom background like this one.

Can Anyone help me, please?

[image: Wave background]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomPainter library in the flutter. This [reference](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/custom-paint-in-flutter-27910dd7f21) will help you get this result.